# How to detect open/closed hand using Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK ver 1.7 C#

Tags: sdk, kinect

I have recently started using Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK to program some stuff using the Kinect the device.

I am busting my ass to find a way to detect whether a certain hand is closed or opened.

I saw the Kinect for Windows Toolkit but the documentation is none existent and I can't find a way to make it work.

Does anyone knows of a simple way to detect the hand's situation? even better if it doesn't involve the need to use the Kinect toolkit.

Comment: Can you please solve this ? I am having error on the "InteractionHandType handType", it says it does not exist in the namespace.. please help me here is my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524420/the-type-or-namespace-name-interactionhandtype-could-not-be-found-kinect-sdk-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I did it eventually:

First things first, we need a dummy class that looks somewhat like this:

```
public class DummyInteractionClient : IInteractionClient
{
    public InteractionInfo GetInteractionInfoAtLocation(
        int skeletonTrackingId,
        InteractionHandType handType,
        double x,
        double y)
    {
        var result = new InteractionInfo();
        result.IsGripTarget = true;
        result.IsPressTarget = true;
        result.PressAttractionPointX = 0.5;
        result.PressAttractionPointY = 0.5;
        result.PressTargetControlId = 1;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, in the main application code we need to announce about the interactions events handler like this:

```
this.interactionStream = new InteractionStream(args.NewSensor, new DummyInteractionClient());
                this.interactionStream.InteractionFrameReady += InteractionStreamOnInteractionFrameReady;
```

Finally, the code to the handler itself:

```
private void InteractionStreamOnInteractionFrameReady(object sender, InteractionFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (InteractionFrame frame = e.OpenInteractionFrame())
        {
            if (frame != null)
            {
                if (this.userInfos == null)
                {
                    this.userInfos = new UserInfo[InteractionFrame.UserInfoArrayLength];
                }

                frame.CopyInteractionDataTo(this.userInfos);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }



        foreach (UserInfo userInfo in this.userInfos)
        {
            foreach (InteractionHandPointer handPointer in userInfo.HandPointers)
            {
                string action = null;

                switch (handPointer.HandEventType)
                {
                    case InteractionHandEventType.Grip:
                        action = "gripped";
                        break;

                    case InteractionHandEventType.GripRelease:
                        action = "released";

                        break;
                }

                if (action != null)
                {
                    string handSide = "unknown";

                    switch (handPointer.HandType)
                    {
                        case InteractionHandType.Left:
                            handSide = "left";
                            break;

                        case InteractionHandType.Right:
                            handSide = "right";
                            break;
                    }

                    if (handSide == "left")
                    {
                        if (action == "released")
                        {
                            // left hand released code here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // left hand gripped code here
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (action == "released")
                        {
                            // right hand released code here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // right hand gripped code here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your answer! I tried adding your code to my project but it says my project does not contain a definition of interactionStream. I am a beginner! Can you please put the entire code in a sample .sln file and share it ? I am running kinect SDK 1.8

Comment: and it also gives error on the "InteractionHandType" you created in dummyclass.. even though I have included "using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction;" Please somebody help~!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28524772/738017) for adding Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction to your project

Answer (score 2):

SDK 1.7 introduces the interaction concept called "grip".  You read about all the `KinectInteraction` concepts at the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188673.aspx

The way Microsoft has implemented this is via an event from an [`KinectRegion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.aspx).  Among the [`KinectRegion` Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion_events.aspx) are [`HandPointerGrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.handpointergrip.aspx) and [`HandPointerGripRelease`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.handpointergriprelease.aspx), which fire at the appropriate moments.  Because the event is coming from the element the hand is over you can easily take appropriate action from the event handler.

Note that a `KinectRegion` can be anything.  The base class is a `ContentControl` so you can place something as simple as an image to a complex `Grid` layout within the region to be acted on.

You can find an example of how to use this interaction in the [ControlBasics-WPF example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188701.aspx), provided with the SDK.

**UPDATE:**

`KinectRegion` is simply a fancy `ContentControl`, which in turn is just a container, which can have anything put inside.  Have a look at the [`ControlBasics-WPF`](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#v1.x/ToolkitSamples1.7.0/C#/ControlsBasics-WPF/) example, at the [Kinect for Windows CodePlex](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/), and do a search for `KinectRegion` in the [`MainWindow.xaml`](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#v1.x/ToolkitSamples1.7.0/C#/ControlsBasics-WPF/MainWindow.xaml) file.  You'll see that there are several controls inside it which are acted upon.

To see how `Grip` and `GripRelease` are implemented in this example, it is best to open the solution in Visual Studio and do a search for "grip".  They way they do it is a little odd, in my opinion, but it is a clean implementation that flows very well.

Comment: Tried it, very limited documentation and hard to figure out how it works.

Just to make sure if I understood you right, I can set anything to be "KinectRegion" ?

Comment: Alright I managed to get the region to works.
However, I cannot find a way to create the event for the grip and gripRelease.

Any insights?

Comment: I got the same problem: I could create a XAML-Element of type "KinectRegion" but i am not able to set its "Grip"-Event-Handler with something like: `<k:KinectRegion HandPointerGrip="kinectRegion_HandPointerGrip" x:Name="kinectRegion">...</k:KinectRegion>`

Answer (score 1):

For what i know Microsoft kinect for windows SDK does not best to detect open and close hands. Microsoft provides tracking of 20 [body](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC584844.png) parts and does not include the fingers of the hand. You can take advantage of the kinect interactions for that in an inderect way. This tutorial shows how:
http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2013/05/03/kinect-interactions-with-wpf-part-iii-demystifying-the-interaction-stream.aspx

But i think the best solution when tracking finger movements would be using [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/) SDK.

Some of the [MiddleWares](http://www.openni.org/software/?cat_slug=file-cat1) of OpenNI allow finger  tracking.

Comment: Unfortunately the code provided in the link does not work for me. I do not know why, the camera won't even start.

Comment: not true anymore. with kinect sdk 1.7 it is natively supported by MS.

Comment: I have tested the code provided by Quicksoul. For me it does work.

Comment: The code does not work for jacob maybe because of the kinect version. Maybe Jacob use xbox 360 version . And the code in the blog tries to active the near mode which is not in xbox 360 version. I also used xbox 360 version. It did not work for me in the beginning but then i made some modifications to the code and started to work.

Comment: @CodingWolf Can you please share a sample working code that detects the fist and grip release gesture? I would really appreciate if you can share it's link. Here is my email : faizan.zad@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
private void OnHandleHandMove(object source, HandPointerEventArgs args)
    {
        HandPointer ptr = args.HandPointer;
        if (ptr.HandEventType==HandEventType.Grip)
        {
           // TODO
        }
    }
```

Comment: it gives error on the "InteractionHandType" you created in dummyclass.. even though I have included "using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction;" Please somebody help~!