# Calculating the Area of the Hand using Depth Data

Tags: c#, computer-vision, kinect, kinect-sdk

Using a Kinect sensor, I am attempting to write an algorithm to detect a clenched fist. I am trying to achieve this by calculating the area occupied by the hand (since clenched fist area < non-clenched fist area).

Here's what I have so far:

- Depth information per pixel (from the DepthStream)
- Location of the Hand (from the SkeletonStream)

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the depth data that corresponds to the hand. It's easy to get the depth data at the exact location that the Kinect gives for the hand, but I don't know how to get all the depth data for the hand. Any suggestions, pseudocode, and/or link to tutorials would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are events from KinectInteractions that detect whenever the fist is in [gripped mode or released mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188673.aspx) as it's used for the KinectScrollViewer in the KinectRegion:

[The HandPointGrip event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.handpointergrip.aspx)
[The HandPointGripReleased event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.handpointergriprelease.aspx)

Also this might be a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729142/how-to-detect-open-closed-hand-using-microsoft-kinect-for-windows-sdk-ver-1-7-c) .

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced in this field but found this in my search. See if it helps you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openni-dev/Kj2JL6K0PBw

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I appreciate it!