# The type or namespace name 'InteractionHandType' could not be found Kinect SDK 1.8

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-interaction, grip

I am trying to detect closing fist (grip) gesture to control my mouse cursor in Kinect.
I followed this tutorial to setup :
http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2013/05/03/kinect-interactions-with-wpf-part-iii-demystifying-the-interaction-stream.aspx

However, in the DummyInteractionClient.cs file, I am getting this error on the following line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction;

using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls;


namespace Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls
{
    public class DummyInteractionClient : IInteractionClient
  {
    public InteractionInfo GetInteractionInfoAtLocation(
        int skeletonTrackingId,
        InteractionHandType handType,
        double x,
        double y)
    {
        var result = new InteractionInfo();
        result.IsGripTarget = true;
        result.IsPressTarget = true;
        result.PressAttractionPointX = 0.5;
        result.PressAttractionPointY = 0.5;
        result.PressTargetControlId = 1;

        return result;
     }
  }
}
```

The error is at InteractionHandType handType. it says , Error   1   The type or namespace name 'InteractionHandType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   E:\work\FYP\working\Kinect Mouse Controller switcher\kinectmouse CODE-96133\C Sharp zoom in both hands\DummyInteractionClient.cs    18  13  Microsoft.Kinect.Samples.CursorControlWhat does it error means? Am I missing or using wrong namespace names?
Please help i am not expert in C# Kinect SDK 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

The **InteractionHandType** enumeration is defined in the namespace Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction.
You need to add a reference to **microsoft.kinect.toolkit.interaction.dll** to your project (you will find the toolkit assemblies in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.8.0\Assemblies).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add a reference to the following *.dll* files:

- **Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction.dll**
- **Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.dll**

They are both placed in *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.8.0\Assemblies*.

After that, you also need to copy the following *.dll* files in your project build folder:

- **KinectInteraction180_32.dll**
- **KinectInteraction180_64.dll**

You can find them in *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.8.0\bin*.